# Question about Fisher information matrix on a statistical model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, information-theory, fisher-information

Consider a family $S$ of probability density functions on $X$ which is defined as $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x\geq 0)$ and $\int_{X}p(x)dx=1$.Suppose each element of $S$ may be parameterized using real-valued variable $[\xi^1,\ldots,\xi^n]$ that is
$S=\{p(x;\xi):\xi=[\xi^1,\ldots,\xi^n]\in E\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}\}$ where $x\in X$.$S$ is known as statistical manifold of dimension $n$.
Given a point $\xi\in E$ the Fisher information matrix of $S$ at $\xi$ is an $n\times n$ matrix $G(\xi)=[g_{ij}(\xi)]$,where $(i,j)^{th}$ element of $g_{ij}$ is defined by the equation below,
$$g_{ij}(\xi)=E_{\xi}[\partial_{i}l_{\xi}\partial_{j}l_{\xi}]=\int \partial_{i}l(x;\xi)\partial_{j}l(x;\xi)p(x;\xi)dx$$
where, $\partial_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^i}$,$l_{\xi}=l(x,\xi)=\log\hspace{1mm}  p(x;\xi)$ and $E_{\xi}$ denotes the expectation with respect to the distribution $p_{\xi}.$

$\textbf{My Questions:}$ (1)   After this author says tha $g_{ij}$ can also be written as $g_{ij}(\xi)=-E_{\xi}[\partial_{i}\partial_{j}l_{\xi}]$ (I am not sure how do we get this but I think we need to use the following property of statistical model which says that $\int\partial_{i}p(x;\xi)dx=\partial_{i}\int p(x;\xi)dx=0.$

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: I tried it but not getting it,can you show the steps.

Comment: It is straightforward.  If the abstraction troubles you, work it out in a particular case, such as a Normal or Exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found, e.g., in Calin and Udriste's *[Geometric Modeling in Probability and Statistics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-07779-6)* (Proposition 1.6.3).

Let us denote $p_\xi(x) := p(x;\xi)$. As you noted, $\int \partial_i p_\xi(x)~\mathrm{d}x = \partial_i \int p_\xi(x)~\mathrm{d}x = \partial_i(1) = 0$. With that, we can write
$$
\int p_\xi(x) \partial_i \log p_\xi(x)~\mathrm{d}x = \int \partial_i p_\xi(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$

Differentiating this expression again, now with respect to $\xi^j$, gives
$$
\begin{align*}
&\partial_j \int p_\xi(x) \partial_i \log p_\xi(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 0\\
\iff &\int \left(\partial_j p_\xi(x)\right) \left(\partial_i \log p_\xi(x)\right)~\mathrm{d}x + \int p_\xi(x) \left(\partial_j\partial_i \log p_\xi(x)\right)~\mathrm{d}x = 0\\
\iff &\int \left(p_\xi(x) \partial_j \log p_\xi(x)\right) \left(\partial_i \log p_\xi(x)\right)~\mathrm{d}x + \int p_\xi(x) \left(\partial_j\partial_i \log p_\xi(x)\right)~\mathrm{d}x = 0\\
\iff &g_{ij}(\xi) = - E_\xi \left[\partial_j\partial_i \log p_\xi(x)\right].
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hi hmiya. Welcome to CV.